# Smith normal form 2

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $m \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{Z}$. If they are related by a row or column operation, then prove that they have isomorphic co kernels. How to prove this? If they are related by a row or column operation can we conclude that they have same Smith Normal Form?